# Как в C# преобразовать массив байт в картинку с растровой или векторной графикой?

Tags: c#, svg, asp.net-web-api

Есть проект, написанный на **ASP.NET Core** с использованием языка **C#**. На данный момент встала весьма не тривиальная задача используя массивы байт создать растровую или векторную графику. Суть следующая

Есть поле, размерностью ***8x8*** квадратов

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Некоторые из квадратов (остальные - пустые, и их можно не трогать) содержат в себе сетку пикселей размерностью ***100*** на ***100*** (т.е., в одном квадрате основного поля ***10000*** пикселей).

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Такие квадраты (которые имеют сетку, т.е., не пустые) представлены в виде массивов следующего типа:

```
byte[] square27 = new byte[] { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 2, 2, 0, 0, 1, ... };//Размерность массива 10000 значений
```

, где **0** - *пустой пиксель*, **1** - *пиксель одного цвета (синего, например)*, **2** - пиксель *другого цвета (голубого, например)*.

Идея такая. Циклом проходить по каждому элементу массива и рисовать точку нужного цвета. На выходе получить растровое или векторное изображение, построенное с использованием квадратиков-пикселей разных цветов.

На выходе нужно получить изображение, но с возможностью увеличения масштаба в 4-6 раз без потери качества и с возможностью в будущем изменять эти цвета на стороне клиента...

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

На сетке...

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Суть вопроса в том, как подобное можно реализовать в **C#**? В интернете не нашёл нужной информации. Может есть какая библиотека, которая может это реализовать? Или может есть какой-то подход в стандартных библиотеках? Очень желательно (но не обязательно), чтобы это работало кросcплатформенно, т.к. используется **Core**.

Comment: Не понятно чего вы хотите, сделать из этого массива изображение или отрендерить его?

Comment: Если речь о пикселях, то зачем вектор? И нужен воспроизводимый пример, который содержит структуру данных полностью. SVG - это по сути XML, чтобы нарисовать пиксель в SVG, нужно 4 точки (или 2 для прямоугольника), то есть вьюпорт должен быть 1600x1600, это огромная куча данных. Уточните смысл всего этого мероприятия, потому что пока оно выглядит очень странно.

Comment: Далее, цвет обычного пикселя задается а RGB, в SVG цвета задаются так же, а у вас как? Как получить цвет?

Comment: @ori из массива построить изображение

Comment: Вы хотите запихнуть растровые пиксели в векторную картинку? А зачем? Действительно непонятно

Comment: @aepot В этом и загвоздка. Да, можно было бы сделать изображение в base64, но мне очень нужны векторы для масштабирования и стилизации. Именно поэтому точка-пиксель (квадрат) должна как-бы строится на основании данных массива

Comment: @andreymal формат приёма данных (т.е. массива с этими пикселями) выбирал не я. У меня лишь стоит задача преобразовать это в векторную графику. Т.е. создать имитацию пиксельной картинки

Comment: Растр тоже прекрасно масштабируется и исходя из того что я вижу, весить он будет намного меньше. Битмап размером 800x800 глубиной 8bpp со своей собственной палитрой можно сгенерить за ~20мс или меньше, и пожать без потерь в весьма маленький PNG8. А дальше растягивайте его стилями как хотите. Хотите - грузите его на фронте в канвас и там перекрашивайте как угодно, здесь уж на сколько фантазии хватит. Плюс потребности все еще непонятны.

Comment: @aepot Вы правы по поводу веса. В идеале, хотелось всё это в векторной графике сделать. Хотя сейчас уже сомневаюсь в том, что эта идея была хорошая. Ваш вариант звучит разумно. Я в этой теме плохо разбираюсь. Подскажите, в какую сторону мне начать копать, чтобы реализовать то, что Вы описали выше. Может есть какой-нибудь простенький пример подобной реализации в C#? Спасибо!

Comment: На чем эта картинка будет отображаться?

Comment: @eri В браузере у пользователя на странице сайта

Comment: Для растра GDI+ `System.Drawing` вам может помочь, но это только под Windows. Для линуксов я графику не делал. Хотя вроде были порты GDI+ и под линуксы, но я честно, не изучал вопрос. Библиотека для винды есть в NuGet пакете **System.Drawing.Common**. Примеров использования полинтернета, в том числе и мои ответы на эту тему здесь есть. Эта же библиотека широко используется в WinForms, так что вы вероятно с ней уже знакомы.

Comment: @aepot Спасибо, что потратили время и убедили в абсурдности моей идеи с векторной графикой. Спасибо за наводку. Буду разбираться ;)

Comment: Идея не абсурдная. Если научиться соседние "пиксели" одного цвета объединять в один общий полигон, то может весьма недурно получиться и в векторе, но это уже другая, непростая задача. А попиксельный вектор - это, само собой, сомнительная затея.

Comment: Подсказка: Если будете работать с System.Drawing, запомните одну ловушку, не используйте GetPixel/SetPixel, никогда. Это примерно в 100 раз медленнее, чем через массив.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решение с растром, библиотека Windows GDI+, NuGet пакет **System.Drawing.Common**.

Так как я не знаю вашей структуры данных, точнее знаю только размер массива для "плитки", придумаю ее сам.

Вот простой пример, как получить PNG 800x800x8bit из похожих на ваши данных. Так же как вы пронумеровали сетку 8x8, чем больше число, тем светлее плитка.

```cs
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int size = 8;
    int tileSize = 100;

    byte[][] data = CreateData(size, tileSize); // пусть это будут ваши данные

    using var bitmap = new Bitmap(size * tileSize, size * tileSize, PixelFormat.Format8bppIndexed);
    BitmapData bmpData = bitmap.LockBits(new Rectangle(Point.Empty, bitmap.Size), ImageLockMode.WriteOnly, bitmap.PixelFormat);
    for (int col = 0; col < size; col++) 
    {
        for (int row = 0; row < size; row++)
        {
            byte[] array = data[col * size + row];
            for (int scan = 0; scan < tileSize; scan++)
            {
                // bmpData.Stride - длина строки битмапа в байтах
                // bmpData.Scan0 - указатель на начало данных битмапа в неуправляемой области памяти GDI+
                Marshal.Copy(array, scan * tileSize, bmpData.Scan0 + ((row * tileSize + scan) * bmpData.Stride + col * tileSize), tileSize);
            }
        }
    }
    bitmap.UnlockBits(bmpData);

    // пусть это будет ваша палитра, вы можете ее передать с клиента в контроллер в виде комбинаций RGB
    // я здесь просто сгенерю градации серого
    ColorPalette pal = bitmap.Palette;
    for (int c = 0; c < 256; c++)
        pal.Entries[c] = Color.FromArgb(c, c, c);
    bitmap.Palette = pal;

    bitmap.Save("image.png", ImageFormat.Png);
}

private static byte[][] CreateData(int size, int tileSize)
{
    int count = size * size;
    byte[][] data = new byte[count][];
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        data[i] = CreateArray(tileSize * tileSize, (byte)(i * 4)); // 0 - 252 с шагом 4, для палитры с градациями серого
    }
    return data;
}

private static byte[] CreateArray(int size, byte value)
{
    var array = new byte[size];
    Array.Fill(array, value);
    return array;
}
```

Результат, вес этой PNG 13 килобайт.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Битмап можно сохранить так же в `Stream` и сразу отдать его клиенту как File attachement. Генерация этой картинки на моем калькуляторе занимает ~8мс.

Comment: Отлично, спасибо. Но хотелось бы 2 вопроса уточнить. Не все квадраты 8x8 имеют значения. В моём случае изображение попадает в квадраты с номерами 27, 28, 29, 35, 36, 37, 43, 44, 45 (но это сейчас, потом может всё измениться). Остальные квадраты совсем пусты и их (грубо) я заполняю нулями. Собственно, первый вопрос - как сделать, чтобы нули(0) не имели цвета (были прозрачные)(что-то находил про transparent, но буду благодарен, если объясните). А второй вопрос - как обрезать область только до квадратов, в которых есть значения, чтобы картинка занимала всю площадь при выгрузке?

Comment: @EgorTrutnev внесите нулевым цветом в палитру прозрачный цвет, например `Color.FromArgb(0, Colors.Black)`.

Comment: @EgorTrutnev а вот с обрезкой сложно, скорее надо проверять на пустые строки и столбцы и создавать изображение уже под полезный размер и рисовать только на нем. Математика+доработка кода, технологии те же.

Comment: Спасибо огромное за помощь. Буду разбираться)

Comment: Задача "обрезать изображение" до границ, в которых есть пиксели оказалась вполне легко решаемой. Достаточно пройти циклом в цикле и найти 4 точки: **MinPositionX**, **MinPositionY**, **MaxPositionX** и **MaxPositionY**. Имея эти данные можно обрезать 'bitmap = cropImage(bitmap, new Rectangle(MinPositionX, MinPositionY, bitmap.Width - tileSize + MaxPositionX- MinPositionX, bitmap.Height - tileSize + MaxPositionY- MinPositionY));'

Comment: @EgorTrutnev только в результате вы могли получить 32-битный битмап, а не 8-битный. А из 32-битного битмапа получается 32-битная PNG.

Comment: Так и получилось. На сколько это плохо? И возможно ли это исправить после моих манипуляций?

Comment: @EgorTrutnev это уже вам решать, насколько. Очевидно, 32-битная png будет весить в 2-3 раза больше. Проиндексировать цвета обратно конечно можно, но зачем? Это же лишние затраты времени. Я поэтому и говорил, что придется повозиться, чтобы сделать быстро и без лишних преобразований.

Comment: Не знаю, на сколько это хорошая идея, но я преобразую фото в base64 и отдаю пользователю. При этом длина строки между 8 и 32 увеличивается примерно на 25%, однако разница в скорости обработки не чувствуется. Это всё ещё работает очень быстро. Осталось разобраться с масштабированием без потери качества и перекраской в canvas. Ещё раз спасибо за поддержку в данном вопросе!

Comment: @EgorTrutnev можете перекрашивать при перегенерации. То есть вместе с запросом на картинку можете отправлять требуемые цвета. Base64 - лишнее, отдавайте как двоичный файл, HTTP это позволяет, выглядеть должно как скачивание любой обычной картинки. Это должно быть просто. Увеличивать можно прямо в браузере. Без канваса, просто закиньте в Image картинку, и поместите в нужное место. Так как границы четкие, мыла быть не должно. А так, можно с канвасом поиграться,да.

Comment: Похоже, что где-то у меня косяк. Размер изображения получился 180x228. Выгружаю картинку в <img> и меняю свойство width у <img> на width=600. Картинка получается мыльной https://i.stack.imgur.com/FEXgz.png.

Comment: При этом хотелось бы видеть поведение, аналогичное GIMP, который увеличивает размер пикселей при приближении, не создавая "мыла" https://i.stack.imgur.com/yybtH.png

Comment: Нашёл вариант, увеличить полученное изображение на сервере var bitmapResize = new Bitmap(1000, 1000);
            using(var gr = Graphics.FromImage(bitmapResize))
            {
                gr.InterpolationMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.InterpolationMode.NearestNeighbor;
                gr.DrawImage(bitmap, 0, 0, 1000, 1000);
            }

Comment: @EgorTrutnev `NearestNeighbor` - увеличивайте кратно, то есть если картинка 300x300, то до 600x600 или 900x900, либо попробуйте другие тыпы интерполяции. Но если вам и так хорошо, то не проблема. 1000x1000 будет нормально так весить. Попробуйте с канвасом в браузере. JS много всяких штук умеет.

Comment: Ох. Громадное спасибо. Сколько лет во фронте, а про это свойство css слышу впервые(. Действительно выглядит очень хорошо

Answer (score 1):

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Color[] colors = new Color[4] { Color.FromArgb(151, 151, 151), Color.FromArgb(87, 87, 87), Color.FromArgb(51, 51, 51), Color.FromArgb(7, 7, 7) };
        
    byte[,] signatureBlock = new byte[16, 16]
    {
        { 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 0, 0, 3, 0, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1},
        { 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 3, 1, 1, 2},
        { 1, 3, 2, 2, 3, 2, 2, 2, 0, 2, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1},
        { 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 3, 1, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1},
        { 1, 0, 0, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3},
        { 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 3, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 1},
        { 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 3},
        { 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1},
        { 1, 0, 0, 3, 0, 2, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
        { 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 3, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 0, 1},
        { 1, 1, 0, 2, 2, 0, 0, 2, 3, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
        { 3, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 3},
        { 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 0, 0, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1},
        { 1, 0, 2, 0, 3, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 2, 1, 1, 0, 0},
        { 1, 1, 1, 2, 2 ,2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 2, 2, 1},
        { 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1}
    };
    Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(signatureBlock.GetLength(1), signatureBlock.GetLength(0), PixelFormat.Format8bppIndexed);
    BitmapData bmpData = bitmap.LockBits(new Rectangle(Point.Empty, bitmap.Size), ImageLockMode.WriteOnly, bitmap.PixelFormat);
    Marshal.Copy(signatureBlock.Cast<byte>().ToArray(), 0, bmpData.Scan0, signatureBlock.Length);
    bitmap.UnlockBits(bmpData);
    ColorPalette pal = bitmap.Palette;
    for (int i = 0; i < colors.Length; i++)
        pal.Entries[i] = colors[i];
    bitmap.Palette = pal;
    bitmap.Save("image.png", ImageFormat.Png);
}
```

Тут мало что осталось от моего кода(Только массив), Всё остальное сделал @aepot

Comment: Не надо `SetPixel`, пожалуйста. И в этом коде весь `switch` блок на `bitmap.SetPixel(x, y, colors[signatureBlock[y, x]]);` можно заменить. Могу показать, как этот код переписать правильно.

Comment: Вот, пожалуйта https://pastebin.com/UL18aCGA, вот результат https://i.stack.imgur.com/NvJMC.png